# How to launch arbitrary amount of Teamcity agents?

Tags: teamcity

I have my worker configuration that would build my APKs in a for loop, but it takes some time to build them all sequentially. I need to split my apk generation to different agents, but it should be configurable via parameters.

For example, I launch initial configuration with parameters: "Apps:app1; Flavors:test,prod". It should trigger worker configuration on two agents:

```
initial - agent1 (build app1:test) - result
        \ agent2 (build app1:prod) /
```

If I launch initial for only "app1:test", It should only launch one agent, that will build app1:test apk.

For "Apps:app1,app2; Flavors:test,prod" it should launch 4 agents, etc

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your case is literally one of the main reasons why TeamCity was developed like it is.

The idea is that you need to have different build configurations for different... well, build configurations. Then, once you connect them in a build chain, they will be triggered in parallel.

Comments to [this](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000877980-Build-parallel-steps) TeamCity support community post have a good explanation of this concept.

The number of agents is not configured by the build configuration. Instead, any build goes into the build queue, and TeamCity allocates an agent that matches the agent requirements set up for the build configuration. Agents themselves belong to agent pools - so, before continuing, make sure you have enough agents in the available pools.